# How to check if an object exists within another object using JS

Tags: javascript

Suppose i have an array of objects

```
var arr= [{name:'John', lastName:'Smith', age:25}, {name:'Steve', lastName:'Johnson', age:56}];
var obj1 ={name:'John', lastName:'Smith'};
```

How to check if an object exists within another object using JS ?

Will nested looping do the trick ? The first loops through the objects inside the array, the second loops through key/value pairs inside the object and compares them to the obj1 key/value pairs ? Is there a better way to do this ? or should i use a 3 loops?

the function should return the obj el in the arr that contains obj1. For example: arr[0] should be returned since it contains obj1

```
function objInArr(srcArr, obj) {

  var arr = [];

  //var srcLength = 0; 
  //var sourceSize = Object.keys(source).length; // The length of the source obj
  srcArr.forEach(function(el) {

    el.forEach(function(objEl){
      obj.forEach(function(sourceEl){
         if( sourceEl === objEl) { arr.push(sourceEl); }
      });
    });
  });

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of **[`Arry#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** and **[`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** methods to loop over your array objects and find if an object with the same keys and values exists or not:

```
var exists = arr.find(function(o){
    return Object.keys(o).some(function(k){
          return !Object.keys(obj1).indexOf(k)>-1 || o[k]!=obj1[k];
    });
});
```

It will return an `object` if it exists, if you want to return a `boolean` you can change the `.find()` with a `.some()`.

Here the statement `!Object.keys(obj1).indexOf(k)>-1 || o[k]!=obj1[k]` will quit if an object doesn't have the iterated `key` or it's  `value` its' not the same.

**Demo:**

```js
var arr= [{name:'John', lastName:'Smith', age:25}, {name:'Steve', lastName:'Johnson', age:56}];
var obj1 ={name:'John', lastName:'Smith'};

var exists = arr.find(function(o){
    return Object.keys(o).some(function(k){
          return !Object.keys(obj1).indexOf(k)>-1 || o[k]!=obj1[k];
    });
});

console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// object contains subObject
function partialContains(object, subObject) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    const objProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
    const subProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(subObject);

    if (subProps.length > objProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (const subProp of subProps) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(subProp)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (object[subProp] !== subObject[subProp]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
const arr= [{name:'John', lastName:'Smith', age:25}, {name:'Steve', lastName:'Johnson', age:56}];

const obj1 ={name:'John', lastName:'Smith'};

const containing = arr.find((object) => partialContains(object, obj1));
```

if `containing` is undefined, nothing was found, otherwise, the object that contains `obj1` is returned.